# Scan Bar code and read it from JSON after store it in recyclerView

Tags: android, json, qr-code

//1.I am trying to pass Bar code value using ZXingScannerView scanner

//2. Then if scanned bar code is equals to JSON barcode object  show item_name and cost from the JSON //file inside recyclerview, My issue is after scanning nothing is showing

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    scannerView = (ZXingScannerView) view.findViewById(R.id.zxscan);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), products_name, cost);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView


    Dexter.withActivity(getActivity())
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    scannerView.setResultHandler(SecondFragment.this);
                    scannerView.startCamera();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Accept The Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                }
            })
            .check();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    scannerView.stopCamera();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    processRawResult(rawResult.getText());
    if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(rawResult.getText()).matches()) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rawResult.getText()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}

private void processRawResult(String text) {
    if (text.startsWith("BEGIN:")){
        String[] tokens = text.split("\n");
        QRVCardModel qrvCardModel = new QRVCardModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].startsWith("BEGIN:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setType(tokens[i].substring("BEGIN:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("N")) {
                qrvCardModel.setName(tokens[i].substring("N:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("ORG")) {
                qrvCardModel.setOrg(tokens[i].substring("ORG:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("TEL:")) {

                qrvCardModel.setTel(tokens[i].substring("TEL:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("URL:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setUrl(tokens[i].substring("URL:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("EMAIL:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setEmail(tokens[i].substring("EMAIL:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("ADS:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setEmail(tokens[i].substring("ADS:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("NOTE:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setNote(tokens[i].substring("NOTE:".length()));
            }

            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("SUMMERY:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setSummer(tokens[i].substring("SUMMERY:".length()));
            }
            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("DTSTART:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setDtstart(tokens[i].substring("DTSTART:".length()));
            }
            else if (tokens[i].startsWith("DTEND:")) {
                qrvCardModel.setDtend(tokens[i].substring("DTEND:".length()));
            }

        }

    }
    else if (text.startsWith("hhtp://")||
            text.startsWith("hhtps://")||
            text.startsWith("www."))

    {
        QRURLMode qrurlMode = new QRURLMode(text);

    }
    else if (text.startsWith("geo:"))
    {
        QRGeoModel qrGeoModel= new QRGeoModel();
        String delims = "[ ,?q= ] +";
        String tokens[]= text.split(delims);
        for (int i=0; i< tokens.length;i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].startsWith("geo:"))
            {
                qrGeoModel.setLat(tokens[i].substring("geo:".length()));
            }
        }
        qrGeoModel.setLat(tokens[0].substring("geo".length()));
        qrGeoModel.setLng(tokens[1]);
        qrGeoModel.setGeo_place(tokens[2]);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"QR CODE PASS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        String json;


        try {

            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("products.json");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"JSON2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

            Log.d("JSONTestLogs", "JSON Raw Text: " + json);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray productsArray = object.getJSONArray("products");
            Log.d("JSONTestLogs", "Fetching the Products array from JSON File. Size: " + productsArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = productsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("JSONTestLogs", "Item: " + i + "\n" + item.toString());

                if (text.equals(item.getString("bar_code"))) {
                    products_name.add(item.getString("item_name"));
                    cost.add(item.getString("cost"));
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); }

    }


    scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(SecondFragment.this);
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"JSON3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

after you scanned the barcode. I think add the barcode to your list here;

```
products_name.add(item.getString("item_name"));
```

After add operation, you did not refresh the recyclerview data.

This code part working just one time.

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), products_name, cost);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView
```

you should call this part again or you need a function inside your adapter which is notify the data of recyclerview.